# expected input from user is 3 strings but if user gives only 2 strings then i want my code to proceed

Tags: c, string

the que is i am expecting 3 strings from user ,but if user types only 2 strings the my code will stop as it is expecting 1 more string .but i need my code to continue anyhow with 2 strings only.so what changes should i do.

```
`enter code here`

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    char c[100];
    printf("enter your name\n");
    scanf("%s %s %s",a,b,c);
    printf("%c%c%c",toupper(a[0]),toupper(b[0]),toupper(c[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*what changes should i do*" - has too many answers, and is therefore too broad in general.

Comment: Have them enter 1 string, which you then parse using `strtok`. Make sure to guard against buffer overflows, something which you are currently vulnerable to.

Comment: Read a line and parse it by yourself.

Comment: Somebody should write the "enter one string and parse it" idea as an answer - probably @JohnColeman as he was first and therefore deserves the points.

Comment: @JeremyP I'm too tired right now to add any details Feel free to post it.

Comment: _"but if user types only 2 strings the my code will stop"_..... __stop__, as in?

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm not going to steal rep

Comment: @SouravGhosh ,i mean if my code is expecting 3 strings from user then in terminal window after having 2 strings from user if user presses enter then cursor will come to new line ,since code is expecting 1 more string.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions by [John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 300

int main()
{
    char strings[3][100] = {{},
                            {},
                            {}};
    char cInputBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    const char delimeter[2] = " ";
    char* token;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter your name\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", cInputBuffer);
    token = strtok(cInputBuffer, delimeter);

    while( token != 0 && i < 3)
    {
        sprintf(strings[i],"%.100s",token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delimeter);
        i++;
    }
    if(i > 1)
    {
        printf("%c%c%c",toupper(strings[0][0]),toupper(strings[1][0]),toupper(strings[2][0]));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter at least personal and family name.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you ,i really appreaciate your help,as i learned a new function from this code.